# Bearer Token is not adding to HTTP request - MSAL2 Angular

Tags: angular, azure-ad-msal

I updated my project to MSAL2.0 angular. Login, logout and guards are working fine. It is not adding any bearer token to any of the request to backend api. MSAL docs says it adds automatically to the request.

I am using
@azure/msal-angular: "^2.0.5",
@azure/msal-browser: "^2.16.1"

Following is my code - app.module.ts

```
 import { msalConfig } from './Shared/azure-config';
    
    export function MSALInstanceFactory(): IPublicClientApplication {
      return new PublicClientApplication(msalConfig);
    }
    
    /**
     * Set your default interaction type for MSALGuard here. If you have any
     * additional scopes you want the user to consent upon login, add them here as well.
     */
    export function MSALGuardConfigFactory(): MsalGuardConfiguration {
      return { 
        interactionType: InteractionType.Redirect,  
      };
    }
    
    export function MSALInterceptorConfigFactory(): MsalInterceptorConfiguration {
  const protectedResourceMap = new Map([ 
    [protectedResources.MainStreetContact.endpoint,protectedResources.MainStreetContact.scopes]
  ])
  return {
    interactionType: InteractionType.Redirect,
    protectedResourceMap
  };
}
    
    @NgModule({
      declarations: [
        AppComponent
      ],
      imports: [
        HttpClientModule,
        BrowserModule,
        UserIdleModule.forRoot({idle: 3600, timeout: 30, ping: 120}),
        AppRoutingModule,
        BrowserAnimationsModule,
        MsalModule
      ],
      providers: [
        {
          provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
          useClass: MsalInterceptor,
          multi: true,
        },
        {
          provide: MSAL_INSTANCE,
          useFactory: MSALInstanceFactory
        },
        {
          provide: MSAL_GUARD_CONFIG,
          useFactory: MSALGuardConfigFactory
        },
        {
          provide: MSAL_INTERCEPTOR_CONFIG,
          useFactory: MSALInterceptorConfigFactory
        },  
        MsalService,
        MsalGuard,
        MsalBroadcastService
      ],
      bootstrap: [AppComponent]
    })
    export class AppModule { }

azure-config - 
export const protectedResources = {
    MainStreetContact: {
      endpoint: "https://app.mainstreetcontact.com/",
      scopes: ['access_as_user'],
    },
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and after some hours of debugging I found a solution which worked for me.

1. Add the web API's `ClientId` like this `api://<client_id>/<scope>` to the protected resources map.
2. If you are sending your requests to your web API from a different module, don't import the `HttpClientModule` there because then the interceptor registration won't work (the other module won't use the interceptor).
3. Add logging -> if you have any further problems then it will be much easier to detect. The MSAL provides logging information about the interceptor so you will be able to tell if it's not being used.

Comment: Point 1 was enough to get things moving again in my case, thanks

Answer (score 0):

for me, it worked by adding the protected resource to MSALInterceptorConfigFactory

```
export function MSALInterceptorConfigFactory(): MsalInterceptorConfiguration {
  /**
   * MSAL Angular provides an Interceptor class that automatically acquires
   * tokens for outgoing requests that use the Angular http client to known protected resources.
   */
  const protectedResourceMap = new Map<string, Array<string>>();
  protectedResourceMap.set('https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me', ['user.read']);
  protectedResourceMap.set('http://localhost:3000', ['user.read']);
  // protectedResourceMap.set('https://graph.microsoft-ppe.com/v1.0/me', ['user.read']); // PPE testing environment

  return {
    interactionType: InteractionType.Redirect,
    protectedResourceMap
  };
}
```

i am unsure of the second param but the Bearer is now added when i call my backend API